# Installing ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: boost, ros

I *can't* be the only person interested in this combination of Cosmic (with Wayland) and Melodic.

I'll be up-front: I seem to have successfully managed this on my XPS 13 (9370), or at least the install script [eventually] completed successfully. However, there's a really hacky workaround. I'll gladly vote up replies of others who attempt an installation, regardless of outcome.

Basically, I ran the instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source for a "desktop" install, and here's how I dealt with the various snags along the way:

- Override the distro, using **bionic** instead of **cosmic**:
  **`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --os=ubuntu:bionic --rosdistro melodic -y`**
- Boost library errors...
  **(See Michal Fapso's solution below. It's quicker, easier, less buggy...)**
  After installing aptitude, switch back-and-forth between Boost 1.65 and Boost 1.67, retrying the installation after each switch. Seriously. The two commands to do this are:
  **`sudo aptitude install libboost1.65-all-dev`**
  and:
  **`sudo apt install libboost1.67-all-dev`**
  Alternate about a dozen times, making sure you get to a higher package number each time. [I think the next generation of ROS will need the Boost date_time function called differently.]
- Random libraries---OGRE, libyaml:
  OGRE can be installed nice and easily with apt (libogre-1.9-dev)
  libyaml... can also be installed, except I tried three or four versions before this one stuck (libyaml-cpp0.3-dev)

---

`roscore` runs, showing melodic version 1.14.3. Turtlesim runs with turtle_tf2_demo (teleoperation), rviz works, as well as rosgraph and the Python (rospy) modules.

Report your errors, please!

Comment: So how is the status now with installation of ROS on Ubuntu 18.10? Is it only possible from source? I tried through sources.list but on update it gives me an "No Release File"-Error. Are there any resources or steps which should be followed when installing ROS on ubuntu 18.10? Or just install from source and deal with snags like you and Michael did?

Comment: Someone else will need to answer; I don't want to bork my installation, and I've moved to using Virtualbox to install ROS2 because of dependency hell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for your hints, Q. Wright. Here is a more detailed guide for ROS beginners like myself :)

This part is from http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source and includes Q. Wright's trick with specifying older ubuntu distro:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
mkdir ~/projects/ros_catkin_ws
cd ~/projects/ros_catkin_ws
rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro melodic --deps --tar > melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall
wstool init -j8 src melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --os=ubuntu:bionic --rosdistro melodic -y
```

Now, before we run the build process, there are boost library errors which Q. Wright mentioned. They are caused by the 'boost::posix_time::milliseconds' function which in newer boost versions accepts only an integer argument, but the actionlib package in ROS, gives it a float on several places. You can list all files using that function:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'boost::posix_time::milliseconds' | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

Open them in your text editor and search for the 'boost::posix_time::milliseconds' function call. Float argument is passed in these files:

```
./src/actionlib/include/actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h
./src/actionlib/include/actionlib/destruction_guard.h
./src/actionlib/include/actionlib/server/simple_action_server_imp.h
./src/actionlib/src/connection_monitor.cpp
./src/actionlib/test/destruction_guard_test.cpp
```

and replace calls like this:

```
boost::posix_time::milliseconds(loop_duration.toSec() * 1000.0f));
```

to:

```
boost::posix_time::milliseconds(int(loop_duration.toSec() * 1000.0f)));
```

and these:

```
boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000.0f)
```

to:

```
boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000)
```

Now we can finally build ROS, hopefully without any error:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Comment: Quick question: did you manage to fulfill and install all the dependencies without any problems? `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --os=ubuntu:bionic --rosdistro melodic -y`

Comment: @avermaet, I don't remember anymore. I followed only few ROS tutorials at that time and I am not using ROS now. But when I run the command you mentioned now, I get this output:
`ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
husky_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [multimaster_launch]
husky_control: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [teleop_twist_joy]
husky_bringup: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [um7]
husky_navigation: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gmapping]
`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Was also not working for me, so I downgraded to 18.04 which is supported.