# ROS Melodic Installation on Ubuntu 18.10 fails at pcl_ros Package

Tags: ubuntu, ros, point-cloud-library

I want to install ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.10 using the non-official instructions from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266574/installing-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-18-10).
Unfortunately, I ran into an issue where it fails to process the `pcl_ros` package.
Did anybody run into the same issue and knows a workaround?

Edit : I am putting a picture of what I get at the  end.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3qpU.png)

Comment: Please post the log and error messages from your installation routine!

Comment: Add Errors or build logs!

Comment: Please add the verbose output of the proposed command (which comes after "Reproduce the Error ...") to your question and build with a single thread: should be something like: `.../env.sh make -j1 VERBOSE=1`